# How do I find and read the header in an mp3 file with java

Tags: java, mp3, frame

Please excuse my noobness, but I think I simply don't know the "name" of what I'm trying to do to look it up.
I've done a ton of reading and I have learned how read an mp3 into an array and I know what the header section looks like and that I'm looking for the frame sync. But I don't know how to "read" the bytes to find the frame sync.
What is that process called?
Can someone explain how to "read" or examine a byte to see if it contains what I'm looking for?
What I'm trying to accomplish is read an mp3 file into an array, then I want to be able to find the frame syncs. I want to find the frame syncs because I want to be able to skip ahead X frames so I can split a large mp3 file into smaller files. I know I have ~26.12 frames / second of music so I need to skip Y frames for Z minutes of music.
I hope that makes sense and someone can tell me what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Step one, get a library that reads mp3s? There are several (e.g., JavaZOOM). Is it even possible to split an mp3 file up without decoding it first? I'm reminded of the time (as a noob) I was trying to get header info from a .wav file. Banging my brains on the variable formatting rules for the type of file--rather unpleasant. Then I realized that Java already has the library to do this. But maybe that experience doesn't apply to this situation.

Comment: Hi Phil. Yes, I've already tried that route and implemented javazoom's mp3spi. Mp3spi worked well for getting the metadata of the file but that is not what I needed. I believe that because every frame of an mp3 file has a header, unlike wav files, i don't need to decode the mp3 to split it. I just need to split at the proper location